# How to find if QuickItem is topmost in QmlScene (z-order)?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, scenegraph

Currently I am developing in Qt / Qml, using QtQuick.
I came to a point, where I need to find out, if an item of my scene is topmost. That is, I need to find if the item has the highest z-coordinate.
I tried to build an algorithm, using childAt and mapToScene. It turned out, that this is horribly slow. Then I found out about itemAt(). Unfortunately, it is only available in GraphicScene, i.e. in the widget world.

Now my question: Is there an equivalent to itemAt() in the QmlSceneGraph? How can I find out, if an item is the topmost one? I do not even need the exact z-order, just to make sure, the item is displayed at top.

Thanks for your help.

Greetings from Germany

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Item::childAt(real x,real y)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#childAt-method) method

```
ApplicationWindow {
   id: root
   visible: true
   MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent
      onClicked: console.log(root.contentItem.childAt(mouse.x,mouse.y));
   }
}
```

Comment: As it says in the opening post, I already tried that. But its buggy (although we were able to fix that bug) and we have to loop through all hierarchies. Just wondering, if there is a native solution in Qt, to find the top item.